# How to create an Unique List with already filtered Rows in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, filtering, unique

I'm trying to make a list of unique names from the list which already been filtered out.
For example:

| Original | W/ Initial Filter | What I want to achieve w/ Unique | Actual output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A | A |
| A | A | D | B |
| B | D |  | C |
| B | D |  | D |
| C |  |  |  |
| C |  |  |  |
| D |  |  |  |
| D |  |  |  |

Is there any way to have B and C not showing since it was already filtered out?

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: So, which one your desired output now?

Comment: What formula do you use for `W/ Initial Filter` column?

Comment: You can use subtotal to find which rows are visible, but as far as I know you would have to use a helper column

Comment: Here is the link for simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZmLRdz0j4ACBUA9sU9tB3L942sftcUEejZTlLbIR4mY/edit#gid=0

Sheet 1 has the "word" and "name".

On the Sheet2, I want to create a unique list of word that is assigned to only "Peter". 

So, the outcome should be "Apple", "Bye", "Elevator". 

But, after filtering word for Peter only on the Sheet 1, then do Unique('Sheet1!A2:A30), then I get unique list of all the word, not just those 3.

Can you guys help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Below should work, considering "Original" data is in column A

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(A1:A, ( A1:A="A")+(A1:A="D")))
```

Comment: Here is the link for simplified version of what I'm trying to do. docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/… Sheet 1 has the "word" and "name". On the Sheet2, I want to create a unique list of word that is assigned to only "Peter". So, the outcome should be "Apple", "Bye", "Elevator". But, after filtering word for Peter only on the Sheet 1, then do Unique('Sheet1!A2:A30), then I get unique list of all the word, not just those 3. Can you guys help with this?